# Doctrine/Symfony: How to manage entities in 2 database?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have 2 database (`default` and `test`). The `default` database is affected for production environment and `test` for development environment. When both database are synchronized, content shall be the same.

So, to manage this request, I have followed this document: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html.

But when I run this command `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql --em=test`, I have `No Metadata Classes to process.`

With the same command for default em, I have no problem.

So, how can I define entities for both database please ?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
More informations about application: The `test` database is for development environment and the structure can differ from `default` database. `test` db will be used to do functionnal test and validate new features. When validation process is done, `test` db structures and data will be merged in `default` db.
This is the strategy to separate production and development environment.

**EDIT 2:**
My config is:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: '%default_database_connection%'
        connections:
            default:
                driver: pdo_mysql
                host: '%database_default_host%'
                port: '%database_default_port%'
                dbname: '%database_default_name%'
                user: '%database_default_user%'
                password: '%database_default_password%'
                charset: UTF8
            test:
                driver: pdo_mysql
                host: '%database_test_host%'
                port: '%database_test_port%'
                dbname: '%database_test_name%'
                user: '%database_test_user%'
                password: '%database_test_password%'
                charset: UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        default_entity_manager: '%default_entity_manager%'
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                auto_mapping: true
            test:
                connection: test
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. Either you want two separate databases **simultaneously** or you want only one all the time (separate for different environments). Or are you after "cloning" your data?

Comment: Can you please share your `config/packages/doctrine.yaml` file?

Comment: Sounds like want to use doctrine/migrations-bundle instead of having two databases

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated question to answer emix and amirmodi.

Comment: And @mblaettermann, not really. In fact, the both db are simultaneously on webserver. We have not deployed a testing toolchain and test the application (connected to mobile App by REST API) directly by an alternative test subdomain.

Comment: That's sounds a bit wrong to me. Why are you even asking, when you do not accept best practise answers you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after many tests and research, I found a solution but with limitation.

1. I completed the configuration as follow:

   ```
   default:
       connection: default
       naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
       auto_mapping: true
       mappings:
           Bundle1: ~
           Bundle2: ~
   test:
       connection: test
       naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
       mappings:
           Bundle1: ~
           Bundle2: ~
   ```
2. The command `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql --em=test` doesn't work (I have the error `There is no column with name 'email' on table 'users_account'.`). I didn't take time to investigate this issue and I have copied all structure of `default` base to `test` base with phpMyAdmin.
3. I can use both connection in same controller like this:

   ```
   $emDefault = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager("default");
   $emTest = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager("test");

   $entity1 = $emDefault->find('Bundle1', 1);
   $entity2 = clone $entity1;

   $emTest->persist($entity2);
   $emTest->flush();
   ```